# Configuring Jetty/Solr log rotation

Tags: logging, solr, log4j, jetty

I'm having issues setting up logrotation with jetty. What I've inherited includes a jetty file with variables, and a jetty-solr file that uses those variable and handles starting/stopping/restarting the service. These files seem to take precendence over the log4j.properties file for log location and rotation. But I can't find any documentation about these files. Therefore I can't find documentation on rotating or using them.

Has anyone used jetty and jetty-solr files to configure log rotation?

Answer (score 0):

According to log4j manuals - you need to use this parameter

```
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10Mb
```

You could pass your log4j.properties to Solr with that param

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:etc/log4j.properties
```

For more information take a look here - https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrLogging

Comment: I am using that and it's not working. It looks like the jetty and jetty-solr file take higher precedence over the log4j.properties.

Comment: so, please share more details, without them it will be hard to find a correct solution

Comment: I'm not sure what more details can be given. I'm asking if anyone has used jetty and jetty-solr files.

Comment: what do you mean by saying jetty and jetty-solr files. I used Solr with Jetty and my logging works in the correct way, that's why I'm giving you an answer